# Getting data out of JSON

Tags: ruby, json

I keep hitting an error.

The path to my data in JSON is

```
["data"][i]["ip"]
```

where `i`is the index.

I tried

```
json_obj.each do |obj|
  list << obj["data"[i]["ip"]
end
```

in order to store the values inside a list array. I keep getting some conversion error. Is there a better way to do this?

---

```
  uri = URI.parse("SITE")
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  req.basic_auth('USER', 'PASS')
  res = http.request(req)

  json_resp = JSON.parse(res.body)

  list = []

  json_resp.each do | obj |
   print obj["data"][0]["fqdn"]
  end
```

Comment: is json_obj actually json, or has it already been parsed ? and what error are you getting?

Comment: You can work with pure json in ruby. Did you turn it into a ruby array? Can you post an example json, and what are you trying to access?

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Comment: error :  no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: json_obj["data"].each at a guess

Comment: Updated. I actually want it to push the ip into an array

Comment: When you get an error like that you're usually trying to access an Array with a string index.

Comment: json_resp["data"].each do | index |
   list << index["fqdn"]
  end

Comment: @R.J.Robinson can you provide the text contents of `json_resp`?

Comment: Its been solved. @TonyHopkinson, if you want to creat an answer, i'll be happy to up vote it!

Comment: @R.J.Robinson, when being asked for additional information, data or code, it should be added to your question, rather than in comments. We can all easily find it in the body of the question, but it's very difficult to piece together the information we need if it's in comments, because they can be spread across comments for multiple answers at different times.

Comment: Oh, Im sorry. I thought I provided the data. I cant post the JSON because its a work thing.  I will remember that for the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `json_obj["data"].each`

json_obj is a hash (or hash like anyway) so you need to pass the key then you can access the array json_obj["data"] points to and use it's each method.

As @tadman says this error is from Array.each not liking a string index, and happens often to me...